# Visual Basic Hospital Stay Calculator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So I am writing this program that should return the total cost of a hospital stay. Everything appears to be working fine, except the most important part...the total cost of the hospital stay. I have looked everywhere for a possible solution, to no avail. The program continues to return $0.00 no matter what I do. No error messages, just $0.00 every single time. I realize I have not included exception handling as of yet, which I will do once I get the kinks worked out. Any idea what my issue is here? Thanks in advance!

```
Const decRatePerDay As Decimal = 350.0

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim NumOfDays As Integer
    Dim MedCharges As Decimal
    Dim SurgicalCharges As Decimal
    Dim LabFees As Decimal
    Dim RehabCharges As Decimal
    Dim TotalCharges As Decimal

    NumOfDays = CDec(txtNumOfDays.Text)
    MedCharges = CDec(txtMedCharges.Text)
    SurgicalCharges = CDec(txtSurgicalCharges.Text)
    LabFees = CDec(txtLabFees.Text)
    RehabCharges = CDec(txtLabFees.Text)

    lblCalTotalCost.Text = TotalCharges.ToString("c")
End Sub

Function CalcStayCharges(NumOfDays As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim decCostOfStay As Decimal
    NumOfDays = CDec(txtNumOfDays.ToString)
    decCostOfStay = NumOfDays * decRatePerDay
    Return decCostOfStay
End Function

Function CalcMiscCharges(MedCharges As Decimal, SurgicalCharges As Decimal, LabFees As Decimal, RehabCharges As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim TotalMisc As Decimal
    MedCharges = CDec(txtMedCharges.ToString)
    SurgicalCharges = CDec(txtSurgicalCharges.ToString)
    LabFees = CDec(txtLabFees.ToString)
    RehabCharges = CDec(txtLabFees.ToString)
    TotalMisc = MedCharges + SurgicalCharges + LabFees + RehabCharges
    Return TotalMisc
End Function

Function CalcTotalCharges(CostOfStay As Decimal, TotalMisc As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim TotalCharges As Decimal
    TotalCharges = CostOfStay + TotalMisc
    lblCalTotalCost.Text = TotalCharges.ToString("c")
    Return TotalCharges
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried step-through debugging to see how the value of `0.00` is computed? You probably have a multiply-by-zero bug somewhere. The problem might be your `CDec` calls, consider using `Decimal.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or stepping through your code?  It should be pretty clear you never set the value of `TotalCharges`

Comment: None of the functions that calculate the charges are ever called

Answer (score 2):

You never set the value of `TotalCharges` and you never call your functions to calculate the total charges.

Change

```
lblCalTotalCost.Text = TotalCharges.ToString("c")
```

To

```
lblCalTotalCost.Text = CalcTotalCharges(CalcStayCharges(NumOfDays), _
                           CalcMiscCharges(MedCharges, SurgicalCharges, LabFees, RehabCharges)) _
                           .ToString("C")
```